# Toshiba Recovery shows error: f3-f000-0018

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop

My fiancées Toshiba Satellite computer had gotten a virus which won't allow her computer to start up past the windows flag. I used Toshiba recovery to reset it to factory defaults. After which I restarted the computer holding the power button and the `#0` for the recovery of factory default.

It finishes the process to 99.9% (CRC file included) but then stops and shows an error message: `f3-f000-0018`.

I don't know what the error means and cannot find an answer on Google or anyone I know. And I am wondering, if it is possible, if a person would be able to wipe the drive manually as a external USB and copy all Windows 7 files from a working computer and replace onto the external drive.

If not, is there another way to fix the hard drive?

Also: I *think* The problem originated from a bad registry file.

Comment: In post title you mention "hdd" error, while you do not refer to that anythere in the text. So what is the actually full error message?

Comment: An answer given on the Toshiba Forums http://forums.toshiba.com/t5/Satellite-Laptops-all-other/help/td-p/373053 claims this is caused by a memory problem. Does the Toshiba recovery console work? Can you run a memory test?

Comment: Thats all it says. Before it completes and ends that text appears. nothing else but a black screen around it.
---
The toshiba recovery console does work and that is what i am currently trying to use to fix it.